# How To Move Files Into Directories based on filename and Count Files

Tags: bash, command-line, jupyter-notebook

I have seen other topics that are somewhat similar to my question, however I am still a beginner and cannot really understand some of the code that is posted.

I have a list of directories that follow either one of the formats, however the numbers at the end are not the same and the abbreviation (UVM) can be from a list of abbreviations.

`jhu-usc.edu_UVM.HumanMethylation450.Level_1.1.0.0/`
`jhu-usc.edu_UVM.HumanMethylation450.aux.1.0.0/`
`jhu-usc.edu_UVM.HumanMethylation450.mage-tab.1.0.0/`

I am hoping to make a script to move the directories and their files recursively from the current directory to a new directory (and create the directory if not already there) based off of the abbreviation (ex.UVM).

Then I want to be able count the number of files ending in *idat in the directories, and output a .txt file that says " For *abbreviation* there are *this many* idat files.

I haven't had much time to vest in figuring this out as of late and my deadline is coming up very soon. If anyone could help me out with this I would greatly appreciate it.

Please forgive me if the question is worded or formatted incorrectly, this is my first post so I tried my best.

Thank you!

Comment: Does anyone know of a way to write for each folder itself (i.e. UVMFOLDER) the number of idat files within the folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
#!/bin/sh

#Definition of where you want the directory to be moved
destination_root="/tmp/stuff"

 function abbreviation() {

    #Default
    destination="${destination_root}/UNKNOWN"

    if [[ $1 == UVM* ]]; then
            destination="${destination_root}/UVMFOLDER"
    fi

    if [[ $1 == BRCA* ]]; then
            destination="${destination_root}/BRCAFOLDER"
    fi

    #Ensure folder is present
    mkdir -p ${destination} 
}


#Loop through all folders matching the prefix
for instance in jhu-usc.edu_*
do
    #Count instances of *idat files and put the result in a.txt file
    echo "${instance} - `find ${instance} -type f -name "*idat" | wc -l`" | tee -a a.txt

    abbreviation `echo "${instance}" | sed s/jhu-usc.edu_//g`

    #Move the folder to the destination
    mv ${instance} ${destination}
done
```

This will create a.txt with content like:

```
jhu-usc.edu_UVM.HumanMethylation450.Level_1.1.0.0 - 3
jhu-usc.edu_UVM.HumanMethylation450.aux.1.0.0 - 2
```

Where 3 and 2 is the number of instances of files ending with idat in the folder.

**Edit**

Changed the output folder where it moves the files - i removed the prefix jhu-usc.edu_. So for example jhu-usc.edu_UVM.HumanMethylation450.Level_1.1.0.0 will be moved to /tmp/stuff/UVM.HumanMethylation450.Level_1.1.0.0

Comment: Thank you! I believe that the counting will work, however I am hoping to move the directory to a new destination based off of the abbreviation it has after jhu-usc.edu_ , so it will be something from a list of 30 abbreviations (UVM, BRCA, BLCA, etc.) that I have if needed. So basically, if it was BRCA then it would create and send to new BRCA directory, or if it was UVM then it would create new UVM directory and send it there

Comment: Thank you.  I added sudo before mv since it wasn't giving me permission. It moves the folders, however I was also hoping for it just to move all like abbreviations to the same folder (so anything with UVM goes to one UVM folder and anything with BRCA goes to one BRCA) and then count how many idat files are in each abbreviation folder (so 10000 idat files for BRCA). Also is there a way to print it out like a sentence (e.g. There are 1000 idat files for BRCA. There are 5000 for UVM.... etc and each on a new line?). Sorry for so many questions, but I really appreciate it!

Comment: See my updated answer :) Now you will have to define all the paths for all the different abbreviations. Or you can use some sort of algorithm to set the path based on the input in the abbreviations() function.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Sorry I've been experimenting with some things.. I just posted an updated version of the script.. I was hoping to see if instead of counting the idat files by individual folders, is it possible to count them by folder, i.e.. for UVMFolder has 10000 idat files. I rearranged the code so that all the files can be present in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
#Definition of where you want the directory to be moved
destination_root="/data/nrnb01_nobackup/agross/TCGA_methylation"

#Delete tar.gz files
find . -type f -name '*tar.gz' -exec rm {} +

#Move all files within cancersubtype folders into current directory to allow ease of moving to specific directories
find . -mindepth 2 -type f -print -exec mv {} . \;

function abbreviation() {
    #Default
    destination="${destination_root}/UNKNOWN"

    if [[ $1 == UVM* ]]; then
            destination="${destination_root}/UVMFOLDER"
    fi

    if [[ $1 == BRCA* ]]; then
            destination="${destination_root}/BRCAFOLDER"
    fi

    if [[ $1 == ACC* ]]; then
            destination="${destination_root}/ACCFOLDER"
    fi

    if [[ $1 == BLCA* ]]; then
            destination="${destination_root}/BLCAFOLDER"
    fi

    if [[ $1 == CESC* ]]; then
            destination="${destination_root}/CESCFOLDER"
    fi

    if [[ $1 == CHOL* ]]; then
            destination="${destination_root}/CHOLFOLDER"
    fi

    if [[ $1 == COAD* ]]; then
            destination="${destination_root}/COADFOLDER"
    fi

    if [[ $1 == DLBC* ]]; then
            destination="${destination_root}/DLBCFOLDER"
    fi

    if [[ $1 == ESCA* ]]; then
            destination="${destination_root}/ESCAFOLDER"
    fi

    if [[ $1 == GBM* ]]; then
            destination="${destination_root}/GBMFOLDER"
    fi

    if [[ $1 == HNSC* ]]; then
            destination="${destination_root}/HNSCFOLDER"
    fi

    if [[ $1 == KICH* ]]; then
            destination="${destination_root}/KICHFOLDER"
    fi

    if [[ $1 == KIRC* ]]; then
            destination="${destination_root}/KIRCFOLDER"
    fi

    if [[ $1 == KIRP* ]]; then
            destination="${destination_root}/KIRPFOLDER"
    fi

    if [[ $1 == LAML* ]]; then
            destination="${destination_root}/LAMLFOLDER"
    fi

    if [[ $1 == LGG* ]]; then
            destination="${destination_root}/LGGFOLDER"
    fi

    if [[ $1 == LIHC* ]]; then
            destination="${destination_root}/LIHCFOLDER"
    fi

    if [[ $1 == LUAD* ]]; then
            destination="${destination_root}/LUADFOLDER"
    fi

    if [[ $1 == LUSC* ]]; then
            destination="${destination_root}/LUSCFOLDER"
    fi

    if [[ $1 == MESO* ]]; then
            destination="${destination_root}/MESOFOLDER"
    fi

    if [[ $1 == OV* ]]; then
            destination="${destination_root}/OVFOLDER"
    fi

    if [[ $1 == PAAD* ]]; then
            destination="${destination_root}/PAADFOLDER"
    fi

    if [[ $1 == PCPG* ]]; then
            destination="${destination_root}/PCPGFOLDER"
    fi

    if [[ $1 == PRAD* ]]; then
            destination="${destination_root}/PRADFOLDER"
    fi

    if [[ $1 == READ* ]]; then
            destination="${destination_root}/READFOLDER"
    fi

    if [[ $1 == SARC* ]]; then
            destination="${destination_root}/SARCFOLDER"
    fi

    if [[ $1 == SKCM* ]]; then
            destination="${destination_root}/SKCMFOLDER"
    fi

    if [[ $1 == STAD* ]]; then
            destination="${destination_root}/STADFOLDER"
    fi

    if [[ $1 == TGCT* ]]; then
            destination="${destination_root}/TGCTFOLDER"
    fi

    if [[ $1 == THCA* ]]; then
            destination="${destination_root}/THCAFOLDER"
    fi

    if [[ $1 == THYM* ]]; then
            destination="${destination_root}/THYMFOLDER"
    fi

    if [[ $1 == UCEC* ]]; then
            destination="${destination_root}/UCECFOLDER"
    fi

    if [[ $1 == UCS* ]]; then
            destination="${destination_root}/UCSFOLDER"
    fi


    #Ensure folder is present
    mkdir -p ${destination} 
}

#Loop through all folders matching the jhu prefix
for instance in jhu-usc.edu_*
do
    #Count instances of *idat files and put the result in idat_count.txt file
    echo "${instance} - `find ${instance} -type f -name "*idat" | wc -l`" | tee -a idat_count.txt

    abbreviation `echo "${instance}" | sed s/jhu-usc.edu_//g`

    #Move the folder to the destination
    mv ${instance} ${destination}
done
```

Comment: I updated my answer. I was hoping to see if I could change the code to count total idat files in each folder, i.e. BLCAFOLDER has 1000 idat files